# Appendix as different chapters

Tags: appendices

I am using the `Legrand Orange Book` as a template but for some reason, the links for my appendix are pointing to previous chapters.  Here is my preamble:

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{book} 
\usepackage[top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=3.2cm,right=3.2cm,headsep=10pt,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25} highlighting throughout the book
\definecolor{mygray}{RGB}{243,243,244}

%========================================================================================
%   Font Settings
%========================================================================================

\usepackage{avant} 
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\usepackage{calc}

% Fonts
\usepackage{textcomp}

%========================================================================================
%   Bibliography
%========================================================================================

\usepackage[refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true,sorting=none,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,abbreviate=false,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{document}

%========================================================================================
%   CHAPTERS
%========================================================================================

\include{Chapters/Chapter1}
\include{Chapters/Chapter2}
\include{Chapters/Chapter3}
\include{Chapters/AppendixA}
\include{Chapters/AppendixB}
\include{Chapters/AppendixC}

\end{document}
```

I wanted to sperate out my Appendix into different chapters so I went with the approach above.  Could somebody tell me why my hyperlinks for the Appendix point to previous chapters?  For example, when I click on the Appendix A link in the `ToC`, it takes me to chapter 1.  Also, in the structure file related to this template, I have:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{hidelinks,backref=true,pagebackref=true,hyperindex=true,colorlinks=false,breaklinks=true,urlcolor= ocre,bookmarks=true,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
```

Comment: You probably receive warnings in your `.log` about duplicate destinations... yes?

Comment: well, i'm pretty sure Werner's right that you have duplicate labeling going on, but it's impossible to say without a complete but minimal working example. right now, everything depends on what's actually behind those `\include` statements.

Comment: The `\appendix` stuff resets the chapter number to `1` for the first appendix and the output format to `A` etc. This **must** confuse `hyperref`, unless `hypertexnames=false` option is used

Comment: @Chritian Hupfer, your solution works.  If I put the hypertexnames=false, the links point correctly now.  Thanks.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Could you please use your comment as an answer?

Comment: @pluton: I'll try to add an answer, but not necessarily the content of the comment. I think, there's a better way. Thanks keeping me informed

Comment: @pluton: Answer added

Answer (score 2):

The MWE by the O.P. isn't compilable (some missing `%` characters etc., `\include`d files we've no access to etc.)

There's neither `hyperref` loaded nor a `\tableofcontents` at all.

I can only guess, but I think that the O.P. uses `\setcounter{chapter}{0}` and `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}` right before the appendix chapter start instead of `\appendix`

This will confuse `hyperref` and force to redo the symbolic anchor `chapter.1` (being the same for the real `Chapter 1` and for `Appendix A` then)

One *cheap* solution is to provide `\hypersetup{hypertexnames=false}` -- this should be the last resort.

The better way is to provide a new anchor name for appendix chapters, say `\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{appendixchapter.\arabic{chapter}} (the`\theH...` commands provide the anchors!)

The best way is to use `\appendix`.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\setcounter{chapter}{0}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\theHchapter}{appendixchapter\arabic{chapter}}
\chapter{Foo appendix}

%\include{Chapters/Chapter1}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter2}
%\include{Chapters/Chapter3}
%\include{Chapters/AppendixA}
%\include{Chapters/AppendixB}
%\include{Chapters/AppendixC}

\end{document}
```